# How can I implement clustering with sequelize ORM i.e. multithreading

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Below is a piece of code I wrote but isn't working. With this code - how can I refactor it to implement multithreading or clustering so that I can utilize the number of cpus and thus improve the performance of my application?

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log('Master ${process.pid} is running');
    for (let i = 0; i < numOfCpus; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log('worker ${worker.process.pid} died');
    });
} else {
    db.sequelize.sync({
        force: false
    }).then(function () {
        app.listen(PORT, function (req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end('hey');
            console.log("==>   Listening on port %s. Visit http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", PORT, PORT);
        });
        console.log(' Worker ${process.pid} started');
    });
}
```

Comment: hello, @corneliouz did you find any solution to your question?

Comment: @chiragsorathiya Nope didn't find a working solution instead i opted for spring boot application to implement the backend which had everything i need

Comment: same as you I have 60000 records and I want to insert these records in MySQL but it's tack more time so i think about clustering or parallel process.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on something similar. I saw in your comment that you moved on to create a Spring Boot application anyways, but just in case, I think your issue came from the callback you passed to the 'listen' method. You wrote the status 200 to the response header then ended the connection with `res.end('hey');`

Perhaps if you just call the 'listen' method and handle any other logic afterwards with the `server.on('listening')` method, it will solve your issue? It seems to work when I test it on my application. This is my bin/www so far, where `app` is an express application, and `db` is the Sequelize models:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
const http = require('http');
const cluster = require('cluster');
const os = require('os');
const config = require('../server/config')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];
const app = require('../server/app')(config);
const db = require('../server/models');

const log = config.log();

const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;

// Helper functions

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */
function normalizePort(val) {
  const port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (Number.isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }
  return false;
}


/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server and listen on the provided port
 */
const server = http.createServer(app);

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  log.info(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
  cluster.on('exit', (worker) => {
    log.fatal(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} just died`);
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  db.sequelize.sync({ force: false })
    .then(() => {
      log.info('Connected to database');
      server.listen(port);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      log.fatal(err);
    });
}

server.on('listening', () => {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? `pipe ${addr}`
    : `port ${addr.port}`;
  log.info(`Listening on ${bind}`);
});

// Handle server errors
server.on('error', (error) => {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  const bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? `Pipe ${port}`
    : `Port ${port}`;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      log.fatal(`${bind} requires elevated privileges`);
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      log.fatal(`${bind} is already in use`);
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      log.info(error);
    // throw error;
  }
});
```